# log4j2 configuring ColumnMapping type using properties format

Tags: jdbc, properties, log4j2

I want to provide type parameter for columnMapping, but type parameter is already taken to specify that I am working with columnMapping.

For now my configuration is

```
appender.message_appender.columnMappings[1].type = ColumnMapping
appender.message_appender.columnMappings[1].name = journal_id
appender.message_appender.columnMappings[1].type = java.lang.Integer # can't have two type parameters
```

I don't understand how to set type of columnMappings[1] to int.

In xml it could be achieved like this

```
    <Jdbc name="databaseAppender" tableName="dsLogEntry" ignoreExceptions="false">
      <DataSource jndiName="java:/comp/env/jdbc/TestDataSourceAppender" />
      <ColumnMapping name="journal_id" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
      <MessageLayout />
    </Jdbc>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible, since the `.type` suffix is already used to indicate the *plugin type* ("ColumnMapping") of the component.

To be able to use the properties configuration the `type` attribute of `ColumnMapping` must be renamed. You should consider [filing a bug report](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues).

Summarizing: you can define the `type` attribute on `ColumnMapping` using the more commonly used XML, JSON or YAML formats. The strict XML and properties format do not allow that.

**Edit:** since version 2.21.0 (cf. [release notes](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/release-notes.html#release-notes-2-21-0)) you can use `columnType` instead of `type` to designate the SQL type of a column:

```
appender.message_appender.columnMappings[1].type = ColumnMapping
appender.message_appender.columnMappings[1].name = journal_id
appender.message_appender.columnMappings[1].columnType = java.lang.Integer
```