# Log4j2 properties file JDBC appender - cast context variable to uuid

Tags: java, postgresql, log4j2, slf4j, log4jdbc

I have the following database table (PostgreSQL)

```
create table audit_read
(
    level text,
    account_id uuid,
    message text
);
```

I want to insert a database record when a logging event occurs. I have therefore the following configuration (properties file):

```
appender.read.type = JDBC
appender.read.name = READ
logger.read = debug, READ
logger.read.name = audit.read
logger.read.additivity = false
appender.read.connectionSource.connectionString=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase
appender.read.connectionSource.type = DriverManager
appender.read.connectionSource.driverClassName = org.postgresql.Driver
appender.read.connectionSource.username = myusername
appender.read.connectionSource.password = mypassword

appender.read.tableName=runtime_audit.audit_read
appender.read.ignoreExceptions=false

appender.read.columnConfigs[0].type = COLUMN
appender.read.columnConfigs[0].name = level
appender.read.columnConfigs[0].pattern = %p
appender.read.columnConfigs[0].isUnicode = false

appender.read.columnConfigs[1].type = COLUMN
appender.read.columnConfigs[1].name = account_id
appender.read.columnConfigs[1].pattern = %X{currentUser.id}
appender.read.columnConfigs[1].isUnicode = false

appender.read.columnConfigs[2].type = COLUMN
appender.read.columnConfigs[2].name = message
appender.read.columnConfigs[2].pattern = %m
appender.read.columnConfigs[2].isUnicode =false
```

When I trigger the logging event I get the following error:

```
ERROR org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.DbAppenderLoggingException: 
Failed to insert record for log event in JDBC manager: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ERROR: column "account_id" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

When I log the logging event to a file I get the following log line:

```
INFO - 0c5c1ad7-14e2-4215-8919-15740d8a8d72 - resource X was read
```

which indicate that my context variables are correctly filled in.

My question is thus how can I cast my context variable to a uuid? I've read the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.12.4/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender) and suspect that I will have to use the ColumnMapping parameter but I can not seem to comprehend how to configure this. Or perhaps something with [UuidConverter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/javadoc/log4j-core/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/convert/TypeConverters.UuidConverter.html)?

Comment: Try adding `stringtype=unspecified` in you jdbc url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.12.4/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender)
that you linked says:

> Note that as of Log4j 2.8, there are two ways to configure log event to column mappings: the original
> ColumnConfig style that only allows strings and timestamps, and the new ColumnMapping plugin that uses
> Log4j's built-in type conversion to allow for more data types

Since you want an UUID, it means that you need to switch to `ColumnMapping`.

The column type is indicated by the `type` parameter; however it creates a [conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75905155/log4j2-configuring-columnmapping-type-using-properties-format)
when using the properties file format, so you will need to switch to another one, for example XML:

```xml
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <JDBC name="READ" tableName="runtime_audit.audit_read" ignoreExceptions="false">
      <DriverManager connectionString="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" userName="myusername" password="mypassword"/>
      <ColumnMapping name="level" pattern="%p"/>
      <ColumnMapping name="account_id" pattern="%X{currentUser.id}" type="java.util.UUID"/>
      <ColumnMapping name="message" pattern="%m"/>
    </JDBC>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="audit.read" level="debug" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="READ"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root/>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Since version 2.21.0, the `ColumnMapping#type` parameter has been deprecated in favor of `ColumnMapping#columnType` (cf. [#1405](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues/1405)), which means that it can be configured through properties again, although I don't recommend using that format.

Answer (score 0):

So - DB expects a UUID, but log4j2 is passing a string. You could simply change the SQL to expect a VARCHAR(40) perhaps, if the contents of the string are otherwise fine?

You also seem to be missing a primary key on your table, and a timestamp, which will likely be useful in any real world system.